# Draw a polyline around a route to act as geofence with leaflet routing machine

Tags: leaflet, open-source-routing-machine, geofencing

I am using leaflet routine machine to get a route between 2 points. I want to be able to draw an invisible polyline around the route and use this as a geofence and if the user goes out of the bounds then reload another route.

Not quite sure how to go about this and the closest thing I have found is this

https://coderwall.com/p/zb_zdw/buffered-polyline

Where do I start?

Most examples use googles routine machine.

Comment: cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54690528/draw-a-polyline-around-a-route-to-act-as-geofence-with-leaflet-routing-machine